# Смена контекста вызова метода java,возможно ли это?

Tags: java-8

Возможно ли в java в методе объекта перекинуть контекст this на новый созданный объект ( ***не вернуть return this*** )
Т.е. ,как создать метод, который "модифицирует" сам себя путем создания нового объекта и переприсваивания  this

Пример-необходимо очистить поля объекта, модифицируя его в методе. И для удобства, чтобы не пробегать по всем полям-модифицируя их-проще создать новый объект с пустыми полями. Но необходимо-не вернуть return new Instance

Смена контекста вызова метода

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
   A a=new A();
   a.f();
    }
}

class A{
    void f(){
        this=new A();//так нельзя
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой в этом смысл? Почему нельзя просто создать новый объект?

Comment: потому ,что метод f() не должен ничего возвращать

Comment: Можно создать новый объект, и вызвать метод от него. Может быть и есть какой-то смысл в том чтобы переиспользовать старый объект, но пока я его не вижу.